# i18n dynamic interpolation arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

Let's say that I have a field witch consist of multiple parts separated by a semicolon (`;`). For example, this would look like the following:

```
'range_numeric; 10; 100'
'length_numeric; 5'
```

The first part will be the key to the translation and any subsequent parts will be interpolation values to be filled into the text. Basically it is passed as a named argument, but I don't want to define keys for each interpolation values and I'm trying to use `I18n` as following:

```
en:
 length_numeric: "%{1} digits"
 range_numeric: "%{1} - %{2} digits"
```

I was trying to pass interpolation values like following:

```
t(:range_numeric, 10, 100) # returns "%{1} - %{2} digits"
```

So, is this possible doing this way? Any suggestions ?

Comment: If you already have a sequence `:range_numeric, 10, 100` (or and array `[:range_numeric, 10, 100]`), then that means your mentioning about your format with semicolon is irrelevant to the question. The question should show the corresponding arrays instead. Please write only things that are relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to interface with rails, but interpolating a string with an array is easy. Use `%s` for simple string substitution. You can even have finer control by using an appropriate format syntax.

```
"%s - %s digits" % [10, 100]
# => "10 - 100 digits"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could convert the array to a hash by the position of the array items:

```
values = [10, 100]
mapped_values = Hash[(0...values.size).map(&:to_s).map(&:to_sym).zip(values)]
t(:range_numeric, mapped_values)
```

(The interpolation keys would start with 0 `%{0}`)

Comment: To avoid the index starting from 0 you could write `(1..values.size)` in place of `(0...values.size)`, it is also more clear, IMO.

Comment: The idea of doing this is a passing arguments without interpolation keys. But thanks you, good suggestion